# How to change a number in an array if there is another matching number (two of the same)

Tags: java, while-loop

Im using a while-loop to check if there is a matching number in an array. But when there is, it appears the loop becomes endless and doesnt stop running

Im very new to java, so I havent tried a lot of things because I dont know what will work and what will not.
I believe the problem lies within the fyllArray or sjekkArray.
NOTE: Im norwegian, so a lot of things I can name myself (variables?) are in norwegian, but I think anyone can understand it.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

class UnikeTall{
    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
    static int[] array;
    boolean likt = false;
    int min = 1000;
    int max = 0;

    private void setArray(int lengde){
        array = new int[lengde];
    }

    private boolean sjekkArray(int tall){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(tall == array[i]){
                likt = true;
            }
        }
        if(likt != true){
            likt = false;
        }

        return likt;
    }

    private void fyllArray(){
        int tall = 0;
        boolean sjekk = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            while(!sjekk){
                tall = (int) (Math.random() * (900) + (100));
                sjekkArray(tall);
                if(likt == true){
                    continue;
                }
                if(likt == false) {
                    sjekk = true;
                }
            }
            sjekk = false;
            array[i] = tall;
        }
    }

    private String sjekkMin(){
        String lavest;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] < min){
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        lavest = "Minste tall er: " + min;
        return lavest;
    }

    private String sjekkMax(){
        String størst;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] > max){
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        størst = "Største tall er: " + max;
        return størst;
    }

    private double gjennomsnitt(){
        int sum = 0;
        double snitt;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            sum += array[i];
        }
        snitt = sum / array.length;
        return snitt;
    }

    public void kjorArray(){
        String utskrift = "";
        int antall = 0;
        int lengde = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("Hvor langt skal arrayet være?"));
//The text in the input box translates to: "How long do you want the array to be?"
        setArray(lengde);
        fyllArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(antall < 5){
                utskrift += array[i] + " ";
                antall++;
            }
            else if(antall == 5){
                utskrift += "\n" + array[i] + " ";
                antall = 1;
            }
        }
        utskrift += "\n";
        utskrift += sjekkMin();
        utskrift += "\n";
        utskrift += sjekkMax();
        utskrift += "\n";
        String gsnitt = df.format(gjennomsnitt());
        utskrift += "Snittet er: " + gsnitt;
        showMessageDialog(null, utskrift);
    }
}

public class oppgaveOblig3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new UnikeTall().kjorArray();
    }
```

I would expect all the numbers in the array to be different. And that happens sometimes, but I believe that only happens when it works on the first try. When there is a matching number in the array, it stops.
But stopping, I mean the loop goes endless and my code stops at that point. Not getting any error codes because my program is still running

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to use a debugger to examine your code, step by step.

Comment: I agree about the debugger but after briefly looking at your code I think it would be much better `likt` be a local variable in the methods you use it to avoid having an incorrect state, same goes for `max` and `min` but they are perhaps less important to change

Answer (score 0):

The `sjekkArray` method is supposed to check whether the value is already in your array, I think. Your problem is because you are using a object variable called `likt` in `sjekkArray` to pass the result of that test to the calling function `fyllArray`. But you fail to set `likt` to false at the beginning of `sjekkArray`. Because it's an object variable, once it is set to true, it will always stay true.

Make `likt` a local variable in `sjekkArray` and use the return value of `sjekkArray` in `fyllArray`.

In general, there are a lot of unnecessary complex ways of doing things in your code. It would be good if you could ask an experience programmer for guidance.